# Bind a PropertyEditor to all fields of a list?

Tags: spring-mvc, model-binding, propertyeditor

In my Spring 3.1.2 application I have a form with a list of objects which will be rendered as a table in the form.  I want to bind a property editor to one field of the list, and there are many other fields that share the type.

I'm trying to use the [`registerCustomEditor(Class, String, PropertyEditor)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#registerCustomEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.beans.PropertyEditor%29) method to bind, and it's not working.  I can bind to all fields that have that class, but that doesn't fit my need.  I've tried using `fieldName` and `*.fieldName` as arguments.  How can I bind to all the fields on the object in the list?

Comment: Could you use polymorphism to solve this?  Break the one stand-out into its own class, then register the PropertyEditor using that class.

Comment: @CodeChimp I think I could, but at this point it wouldn't be preferable.

Comment: Well, if the "field" in the registerCustomEditor works the same as all the other Spring MVC stuff I have seen, like binding errors, all require a fully qualified field name.  So, if you are using a list in a form bean, it would look something like "formBean.listName[0]" for the first element.

Comment: @CodeChimp Yes, I just implemented a hack that adds the validator to multiple rows by looping.  Not a great solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bit of a hack in the `InitBinder` to find all the appropriate properties and add the `PropertyEditor` to each:

```
@InitBinder("detailForm")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) throws Exception {
    for (String param : request.getParameterMap().keySet()){
        if (param.endsWith("currencyAmount")){
            binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, param, new CurrencyPropertyEditor());
        }
    }

}
```